# zmq pub sub does not work even when the topic is set

Tags: c, zeromq

i am trying to make a simple PUB/SUB code, but nothing is received. i set the topic to nothing but still it does not receive. what am i doing wrong? i set the topic to empty so that it reacts to everything, i also tried to set the topic to "test", still nothing happens.

**PUB**

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    void *context = zmq_init(1);
    void *socket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    zmq_connect(socket, "tcp://127.0.0.1:12345");
    sleep(1);
    char message[15] = "test\n";
    while(1) {
        zmq_send(socket, message, 15, 0);
        sleep(2);
        printf("sending..\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**SUB**

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    void *context = zmq_init(1);
    void *socket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    zmq_connect(socket, "tcp://127.0.0.1:12345");
    zmq_setsockopt(socket, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);

    char string[15] = "";
    while(1) {
        zmq_recv(socket,string,15,0);
        printf("i has received\n");
        printf("%s\n", string);

        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to check the return value of all non-void functions because many functions will use the return value to indicate possible errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your publisher and subscriber are calling `zmq_connect`. Because neither is *listening* for a connection, they will never establish a successful connection. You need to pick one of them as the listener. For example, modify `pub.c` so it looks like:

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    void *context = zmq_init(1);
    void *socket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);

    /*
     * Call zmq_bind so that the publisher is listening for
     * connections.
     */
    if (-1 == zmq_bind(socket, "tcp://127.0.0.1:12345")) {
        perror("zmq_connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    sleep(1);
    char message[15] = "test\n";
    while(1) {
        if (-1 == zmq_send(socket, message, 15, 0)) {
            perror("zmq_send");
            exit(1);
        }
        sleep(2);
        printf("sending..\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You'll note I've added some error checking here as well.